# How to call PostgreSQL 13 stored procedure (no function) with cursor INOUT parameter from Npgsql 4.1.5.0 in C#

Tags: c#, npgsql, postgresql-13

I have this Stored Procedure with IN char parameter and INOUT cursor parameter:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_ObtenerFacturaPorNombreCliente(IN p_nombreCliente CHAR, INOUT p_cursorFacturas REFCURSOR)
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL 
AS 
$$
BEGIN
    OPEN p_cursorFacturas FOR
    SELECT "CodigoFactura", "NombreCliente", "DireccionCliente", "TelefonoCliente", "Fecha", "SubTotal", "Iva", "ValorIva", "Total", "Geografico", "Geometrico" FROM "Factura"
    WHERE "NombreCliente" = p_nombreCliente
    ORDER BY "CodigoFactura";
END
$$
```

The stored procedure calling with Npgsql 4.1.5.0 in C#:

```
NpgsqlConnection npgsqlConnection = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=mybase;User Id=user;Password=password;");
npgsqlConnection.Open();
npgsqlConnection.TypeMapper.UseNetTopologySuite();
string sentencialSQL = "CALL SP_ObtenerFacturaPorNombreCliente(:p_nombreCliente, :p_cursorFacturas);";
NpgsqlCommand npgsqlCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(sentencialSQL, npgsqlConnection);
// ===============================
NpgsqlParameter npgsqlParameter1 = new NpgsqlParameter();
npgsqlParameter1.ParameterName = ":p_nombreCliente";
npgsqlParameter1.Value = "Perico de los palotes";
npgsqlParameter1.NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text;
npgsqlParameter1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
npgsqlCommand.Parameters.Add(npgsqlParameter1);
// -------------------
NpgsqlParameter npgsqlParameter2 = new NpgsqlParameter();
npgsqlParameter2.ParameterName = ":p_cursorFacturas";
npgsqlParameter2.Value = string.Empty;
npgsqlParameter2.NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Refcursor;
npgsqlParameter2.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
npgsqlCommand.Parameters.Add(npgsqlParameter2);
// ===============================
npgsqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text; // CommandType.StoredProcedure is with Function
NpgsqlDataReader npgsqlDataReader = npgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

With: `npgsqlParameter2.Value = string.Empty;` I have this error:

> 42601: syntax error at or near <<:>>

With: `npgsqlParameter2.Value = null;` I have this error:

> Parameter :p_cursorFacturas must be set

UPDATE:

With @madreflection suggestion, I changed `null` by `DBNull.Value` but the calling changed `npgsqlParameter2` with "<unnamed portal 1>"

```
NpgsqlConnection npgsqlConnection = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=mybase;User Id=user;Password=password;");
npgsqlConnection.Open();
npgsqlConnection.TypeMapper.UseNetTopologySuite();
string sentencialSQL = "CALL SP_ObtenerFacturaPorNombreCliente(:p_nombreCliente, :p_cursorFacturas);";
NpgsqlCommand npgsqlCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(sentencialSQL, npgsqlConnection);
// ===============================
NpgsqlParameter npgsqlParameter1 = new NpgsqlParameter();
npgsqlParameter1.ParameterName = ":p_nombreCliente";
npgsqlParameter1.Value = "Perico de los palotes";
npgsqlParameter1.NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text;
npgsqlParameter1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
npgsqlCommand.Parameters.Add(npgsqlParameter1);
// -------------------
NpgsqlParameter npgsqlParameter2 = new NpgsqlParameter();
npgsqlParameter2.ParameterName = ":p_cursorFacturas";
npgsqlParameter2.Value = DBNull.Value;
npgsqlParameter2.NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Refcursor;
npgsqlParameter2.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
npgsqlCommand.Parameters.Add(npgsqlParameter2);
// ===============================
npgsqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text; // CommandType.StoredProcedure is with Function
NpgsqlDataReader npgsqlDataReader = npgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use Null as parameter in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20061762/use-null-as-parameter-in-sql)  Although that question/answer has to do with SQL Server, it applies almost universally across ADO.NET providers, including Npgsql.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute Anonymous Block PL/pgSQL (PostgreSQL 13) from Npgsql 4.1.5.0 in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64409013/how-to-execute-anonymous-block-pl-pgsql-postgresql-13-from-npgsql-4-1-5-0-in-c)

Comment: @madreflection Thanks, with npgsqlParameter2.Value = DBNull.Value; and npgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); I can call the Stored Procedure, but npgsqlParameter2 update with: "<unnamed portal 1>", how I could get the cursor values?

Comment: @CaiusJard That's another question that I asked :)

Comment: @Ejrr1085: Use `ExecuteReader` instead.

Comment: @madreflection With ExecuteReader is the same: "<unnamed portal 1>"

Comment: Don't look at the value of the parameter. Using `ExecuteReader`, Npgsql will translate the parameter to a reader. Anyway, this is a different question from what was originally asked.

Comment: @madreflection Not is the different question, is the same, my attempts give no result: with npgsqlParameter2.Value = string.Empty: 42601 syntax error at or near <<:>>, with npgsqlParameter2.Value = null: Parameter :p_cursorFacturas must be set, with DBNull.Value npgsqlParameter2: "<unnamed portal 1>", not is the solution.

Comment: @madreflection This is a duplicate question of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58979996/2825284 and I see no exist solution.

Comment: Why is your ref cursor parameter declared as input when you send no values in?

Comment: I believe that we would use ExecuteReader for a FUNCTION that RETURNS a refcursor, but if it s stores procedure we would Read the refcursor parameter after ExecuteNonQuery

Comment: @CaiusJard The first parameter is declared as input and is a text, the second parameter is the ref cursor and declared as InputOutput.

Comment: @CaiusJard Yeah, the old Functions are better in this case, but I have a program which handle many DBMS: SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL etc. And this program has a standart already defined with functions and stored procedures, and the new PostgreSQL update is these Stored Procedures, so I need create a stored procedure similar to SQL Server and Oracle with PostgreSQL, Oracle with ODP NET work successful, but with Npgsl I see problems.

Comment: @CaiusJard: In my tests of *procedures* (not functions) with Npgsql 4, I've seen that `ExecuteReader` translates the parameter to the returned reader object. You can ignore the parameter entirely. I tried telling OP that above but it didn't stick. I can't remember why I have it as in/out in my test, but I do. I might not have been able to get it to work as out-only. I don't use PostgreSQL regularly. It was for a hobby library project.

Comment: My question there would be what of procedures that have two or more out refcursors? Which is the one that is executereader'd?

Comment: @CaiusJard: I spoke too quickly. I just discovered that I had named the object with "proc_" but recreated it as a function "temporarily" to try something and forgot to change it back before setting the work aside. Npgsql cannot read from a cursor by way of output parameter.

Comment: @Ejrr1085: Cursors are read using [`FETCH ALL IN "<unnamed portal 1>";`](http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/return_result_set_from_stored_procedure) upon return from a *function*. Try wrapping your stored procedures in functions and using a new command object to execute the `FETCH ALL IN` statement.

Comment: @madreflection That is I tried explain inmediatly after ExecuteNoQuery I tried ExecuteReady with FETCH ALL IN "<unnamed portal 1>", but not recognize "<unnamed portal 1>", and ExecuteReady has only a string: "<unnamed portal 1>".

Comment: @madreflection "Npgsql cannot read from a cursor by way of output parameter" It is a real pity, because PostgreSQL has this new Stored Procedures since version 11 and now is version 13, but Npgsql is outdated.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? @Ejrr1085

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. This post helped me a lot. Here's the answer for others.

```
//transaction is needed to keep unnamed portal 1
var transaction = npgsqlConnection.BeginTransaction();

//create the command and add all the parameters, command type, etc 

...

npgsqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 

npgsqlCommand.CommandText = "call your_procedure(:parameters)";

//execute the original procedure with ExecuteNonQuery
npgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

//change the command text and execute the reader
npgsqlCommand.CommandText = "fetch all in \"<unnamed portal 1>\"";

var npgsqlDataReader = npgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{  
    // do whatever is needed to extract the data
}

//clean up
transaction.Commit();
npgsqlConnection.Close();
```